# Write Oracle SQL query to fetch from Tasks table top Approval Statuses that appear after some first null value

Tags: sql, oracle

Write Oracle SQL query to fetch from Tasks table top Approval Statuses that appear after some first null value in the Approval_Status Column and then Approval Status sequence and then some null values

## Facts

- I only need the top Approval Statuses sequence
- Serial Number for each task ID Sequence starts from 1 and then comes in Sequence like 1.2.3... and so on
- There are thousands of tasks in the table like from T1 .... Tn
- See the Query Result below i need to write a query that returns data in that format
- I have heard analytic function i.e. "Partition By clause" for this can be used but i don't know how to use that

## Tasks

[image]

## Query Result

[image]

I really appreciate experts help in this regard
Thanks

Comment: Can you set up a SQL Fiddle for this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with analytic functions, but there is a trick.  The idea is to look only at rows where `approval_status` is not null.  You want the first group of sequential serial numbers in this group.

The group is identified by the difference between a sequence that enumerates all the rows and the existing serial number.  To get the first, use `dense_rank()`.  Finally, choose the first by looking for the ones with a rank equal to 1:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank(diff) over (partition by taskid) as grpnum
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by taskid order by serial_number) -
                    serial_number
                   ) as diff        
            from tasks
            where approval_status is not null
           ) t
      ) t
where grpnum = 1;
```

Comment: i have tried above but there seems to be a problem with syntax in the following query segment ---  select t.*, dense_rank(diff) over (partition by taskid) as grpnum ---- it gives error missing WITHIN Keyword

Comment: thanks with a bit modification i got what i needed .. Thanks a lot for your immediate response Gordon Linoff